# Any way to stop Drupal css from dynamically resizing pages?

Tags: 6, theming

We recently upgraded from Drupal 5.x to 6.22 and one thing noticed right away was that when the browser was taken off full-page the displayed page content would reformat into a very undesirable order.  Previously the page would not resize and users could focus on only a small portion of the screen when in a windowed mode.  This was true for mobile displays as well.
Is there any 'simple' way to prevent this from happening?  I realize this might be a css issue of which I am no expert.  But because this entire site is generated and delivered via Drupal I thought I would ask others.

Comment: This is without a doubt a theme layer / css issue.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Do you have an example URL?  There are too many possible problems here. Though as @Jimaiamma said, this is likely a CSS issue.

Comment: Try other themes like Acquia etc and see if it works

Comment: Try our main site www.law.uconn.edu at full sized browser then window the display and vary the size.  You will see the reactive/responsive formatting.  We would like the formatting to stay consistent.  Not shrink, but as the window size gets smaller the user just sees less and less of the page (as it worked on version 5)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some css to various places in your theme, then. Give a '[width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)' attribute to the divs that contain the pieces of your page.

You may also be interested in 'min-width' and 'max-width' attributes.

Check out the drupal [theming guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme), or better yet, the README in your active theme's folder, to learn where and how to add the css. You don't have to be an expert- with just a little bit of time, this should be pretty easy.